# How to copy Finder path to Parallels Windows Explorer?

Tags: finder, parallels-desktop

I often have deep nested files. For example:
`Users/myname/topic/subtopic/project/aspect/subaspect/myfile.pdf`

It's easy to navigate to this folder in Finder by using programs like Alfred which can do a quick folder search.

Occasionally, I need to do something with a file using Windows Parallels.

I have mapped my home directory (i.e., `Users/myname`)to the Z drive in Parallels.

However, it is quite tedious to navigate to the required folder in Windows Explorer. I'd like to be able to quickly navigate to the folder in Windows Explorer by for example dragging and dropping the Finder path into Windows Explorer or copying the Finder path into the Windows Explorer path. But neither of these actions work.  dragging the folder into windows Explorer, copies the folder, and OSX paths don't work directly (OSX uses slash / and windows uses backslash \, and there is the issue that the paths are remapped).

So in summary, my question is as follows:

- Is there a quick way of making the Windows Explorer folder in Parallels the same as the path in a designated Finder window on OSX?

Answer (score 3):

Check your Services option the Context Menu. Right click your `Users/myname/topic/subtopic/project/aspect/subaspect` folder in Finder. You should see "Reveal in Windows":

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: +1 that looks like a good solution. Unfortunately, I don't have that service running. I'm running Parallels 9. I wonder if it's a version issue or if the service needs to be activated?

Comment: You are right. The service is part of Parallels 11. `/Applications/Parallels Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/ServicesMenu.strings` has the service `"Reveal in Window"` defined.

Answer (score 1):

Another Method is to drag your folder from the Finder onto the Virtual Machine in your Dock. It will open an Explorer window in that VM with your folder loaded. As with the first answer, I don't know if this is specific to Parallels 11 or not.

Comment: +1 It looks like I might need to upgrade from Parallels 9. I think I saw some discussion of this strategy in some Parallels 10 documentation.

Comment: Hi Jules, just a reminder that you can _edit_ your answer to add more info and this is the preferred approach.

Comment: Yes I know. I wasn't sure which way to go with it, because it was a different answer/method.